# Incorrect number of parameters for function 'CASE()'. Expected 6, received 7

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field

This is my code:

```
if ( loan__Funding_in_Tranches__c = TRUE , CASE(ISPICKVAL(loan__Frequency_of_Loan_Payment__c,'Weekly') , 
Ceiling (( loan__Maturity_Date_Current__c - TODAY() ) / 7 ) , ISPICKVAL(loan__Frequency_of_Loan_Payment__c,'Bi-weekly'), 
Ceiling (( loan__Maturity_Date_Current__c - TODAY() ) /14), ISPICKVAL(loan__Frequency_of_Loan_Payment__c,'Monthly') , 
(MONTH(loan__Maturity_Date_Current__c) + (12*(YEAR(loan__Maturity_Date_Current__c)-YEAR(TODAY()))) - MONTH(TODAY())),"")
, loan__Number_of_Installments__c - No_of_Bills_generated__c)
```

Comment: There are several problems here. Maybe consider explaining (using words not code) what you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: i have a requirement here  checking 1st IF condition=true then enter the CASE statements otherwise false condition on the last.

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/317952/edit) the question to add required detail.

Comment: added required details in the above comment

Comment: Expecting later people (trying to make use of existing questions and answer) to read through comments is not very helpful, which is why I asked you to edit the question to add more information. My answer is, due to the lack of such information, rather generic and you'll have to work out the specific details for yourself.

Comment: In addition to putting those details in the wrong place (use an [edit]) as mentioned, you still have not explained what you are trying to do, just how.

Comment: Changed the code as suggested, But the issue is still there:   if ( loan__Funding_in_Tranches__c = TRUE , CASE(ISPICKVAL(loan__Frequency_of_Loan_Payment__c,'Weekly' , 
Ceiling (( loan__Maturity_Date_Current__c - TODAY() ) / 7 ) , 'Bi-weekly', 
Ceiling (( loan__Maturity_Date_Current__c - TODAY() ) /14), 'Monthly' , 
(MONTH(loan__Maturity_Date_Current__c) + (12*(YEAR(loan__Maturity_Date_Current__c)-YEAR(TODAY()))) - MONTH(TODAY()))),"")
, loan__Number_of_Installments__c - No_of_Bills_generated__c)

Answer (score 2):

You would find it much easier to follow what is wrong by ensuring you apply some formatting to your formula expression, such as this:

```
IF(loan__Funding_in_Tranches__c = TRUE,
   CASE(ISPICKVAL(loan__Frequency_of_Loan_Payment__c, 'Weekly'), CEILING((loan__Maturity_Date_Current__c - TODAY()) / 7),
        ISPICKVAL(loan__Frequency_of_Loan_Payment__c, 'Bi-weekly'), CEILING((loan__Maturity_Date_Current__c - TODAY()) / 14),
        ISPICKVAL(loan__Frequency_of_Loan_Payment__c, 'Monthly'), (MONTH(loan__Maturity_Date_Current__c) + (12 * (YEAR(loan__Maturity_Date_Current__c) - YEAR(TODAY()))) - MONTH(TODAY())),
        ""),
   loan__Number_of_Installments__c - No_of_Bills_generated__c)
```

This reveals that your CASE statement clearly fails to follow the structuring required, which is:

```
CASE(field-or-other-value-to-compare,
     a-value-to-compare-with, a-result,
     a-value-to-compare-with, a-result,
     ...
     a-default-result)
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5) for more detail (you'll need to search for "CASE").

Comment: Also using CASE on conjunction with ISPICKVAL makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: And also no need to ever compare check boxes to true.